# Setting up Pi Zero W Wi-Fi through USB SSH

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, usb, boot

I am having lots of problems connecting my raspberry pi zero to wifi. I have followed a number of tutorials.

### 1. What I have tried

This was my wpa_supplicant.conf file

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
#country=GB
network={
    anonymous_identity='@uni.ac.uk'
    ca_cert='/etc/ssl/certs/QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem'
    ssid="eduroam"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    eap=PEAP
    identity="username@uni.ac.uk"
    password="password"
    # phase1="peaplabel=0"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

I created the `ssh` file on the sd card. I also enabled SSH through the `raspi-config` interface.

My `ifconfig -a` looks like the following:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 370  bytes 36228 (35.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 370  bytes 36228 (35.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.238.3  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::cdde:7301:7ba4:81d3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 26:2e:19:0e:bb:4c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1459  bytes 139893 (136.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1424  bytes 224015 (218.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:e9:8e:33  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I tried turning the wlan0 on using:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power on
```

### 2. The error messages I get

When I try scanning for wifi networks using

a) `iwlist wlan0 scan`

```
Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant
```

b) through the `raspi-config` network options

```
Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant

There was an error running option N2 Wi-fi
```

A major problem is that I only have a 4GB SD card and so I installed the [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) OS. But then to install the [GUIs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=133691) I need wifi.

### 3. The question

I want to run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xinit
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-ui-mods
```

Since I have managed to SSH into my Pi Zero W through USB - can I not use the internet from my laptop to download the packages.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: You may be wasting your time.  It may be simpler to get an 8GB or larger SD card.  What you want may not actually fit on a 4GB card.

Comment: Fair enough! Is there any reason why the wifi connection might not be working? Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm afraid my wifi knowledge is too limited to offer any suggestions.

Comment: try `sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` on the command line - what errors do you see

Comment: You cannot communicate e with wpa_supplicat because it is not there.

Comment: `Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Line 5: failed to parse anonymous_identity ''@ox.ac.uk''.
Line 5: failed to parse anonymous_identity ''@ox.ac.uk''.
Line 6: failed to parse ca_cert ''/etc/ssl/certs/QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem''.
Line 6: failed to parse ca_cert ''/etc/ssl/certs/QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem''.
Line 15: failed to parse network block.
Line 19: failed to parse id_str ''="hotspot"'.
Line 19: failed to parse id_str ''="hotspot"'.
Line 20: failed to parse network `

Comment: Awesome! So I went through and fixed these errors - now it is telling me: `Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant ... wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:aa:11:22:33:44 completed [id=0 id_str=]`

Comment: So now if I restart will it automatically connect to the wifi? If not what commands can I run to connect it? Thank you very much!